# is it possible to get the authorization code with google one tap signin?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am trying to get the authorization code after someone clicks on the one tap i am getting the client id and credentials.but i wanted to get the authorization code so i can get the access token basically i am getting the access token but i am not getting the refresh token.so how can i get the refresh token can anybody suggest any solution and here is my code

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=authorize"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Infinity</h2>
    <div
      id="g_id_onload"
      data-client_id="xxx"
      data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
    ></div>
    <script>
      function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        const config = {
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage",
          client_id: "xxx",
          immediate: true,
          response_type: "permission",
        };
        console.log(response, "here i am getting the credentials and client_id");
        gapi.auth2.authorize(config, function (response) {
         
          console.log(response,'here i am getting the access token ');
          // i wanted the refresh token 
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Were you able to get the authorization code? I'm also on the same boat.

Comment: Did you get something for this? I am also facing same.

Answer (score 2):

To get a code that can be exchanged to a refresh token, the OAuth consent page must be displayed and get approved by the end user (even when all the requested scopes have been approved for your client before).
The root reason is, the refresh token represents a long-term permission granting. The user must know and approve this.

In summary, it's impossible to get a code (for a new refresh token) silently. It doesn't matter whether Google One Tap is used or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the user's email, you can call the OAuth URL with login_hint: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?login_hint=user_email           &scope=scopes&response_type=code&state=respond_with_code&redirect_uri=redirect_uri&client_id=client_id`, it won't open the consent screen,
The only drawback of calling this URL is that it will redirect the user to redirect_uri, but you will get the authorization code.